# How to get percentage answer from pivot data?

Tags: excel

Suppose I have the following fields in my Pivot Table:
agent | actual sales

Now I want to add another field which will calculate the percentage of actual sales to the total sales. How do I write the formula for calculated field?

Comment: But I want it to be on a separate column...Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You want to "add anohter field" which you want to be "on a separate column". Separate from what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit: ] If you want to do this type of calculation in a calculated field in the Pivot Table, I'm afraid it will not work as you can only access certain variables from such a calculation. It is explicitly stated in the [Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-values-in-a-PivotTable-report-697406b6-ee20-4a39-acea-8128b5e904b8) that "[f]ormulas cannot refer to totals" giving you a hard time to calculate your percentages.

But if you on the other hand will the calculation in a "separate column" you can do it in the sheet below, either using `=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of sales2";$E$3;"agent";E4)` or `=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of sales";$E$3;"agent";E4)/GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of sales";$E$3)`in the first row of the separate column.

However trivial, my original answer contain the straightforward way:

In Excel 2010 at least, you can in the Value Field Settings dialouge choose to show the values in your actual sales column as "% of Grand Total" among other calculations. Observe that this is not just a formatting, it actually calculates the values: 
[image]